# Set of Exceptional Points of a rational map is finite

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

Given a rational map $R:\widetilde{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \widetilde{\mathbb{C}}$, the exceptional points are points with a finite orbit.

Apparently the set of exceptional points is finite. However, a rational map has infinitely many periodic points, and aren't they not all exceptional?

Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: That is Lemma 3.6 in [Milnor: Dynamics in one complex variable: introductory lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201272)

Comment: Ok, what I'm doing may sound silly, but I'm trying to prove that the set is finite and then use a theorem I have that states that a finite completely invariant set has at most two elements. So, is there a more general result that shows that the set is finite, and not that is has atmost two elements?